# Collapse only selected content beneath a heading in word

Tags: ms-word

When I am creating a heading in a word document and adding content to it, it is collapsing all the paragraphs added after the heading. But I want only few lines of text to be collapsed and retain the remaining. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collapsing headings always collapsed everything below the heading. There is no option in Word allowing you to only partially collapse the text.

A collapsed heading is indicated by an outlined triangle to the left of the heading text as you can see here:

[image]